# Add Alphabetical Scroll Bar to List View in an Android App Using Phonegap

Tags: android, jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile, dreamweaver

I'm new to android app development and I'm currently building a simple song book app with a list view on the home page showing a list of songs. Clicking on the songs will take you to a page with it's lyrics.

I'm using Dreamweaver CC and Phonegap. It's been a really easy process and I've got everything pretty much done. I just need to add an alphabetical scroll bar to the right side of the list like most list applications have.

Here's my index page code:

```
<div id="page" data-role="page">
<div data-role="header">
  <h1>Song Book</h1>
</div>
<div data-role="content">   
    <ul data-role="listview">
        <li data-role="list-divider" data-theme="c">A</li>
            <li><a href="#page2">A Common Love</a></li>
            <li><a href="#page3">Song 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#page4">Song 3</a></li>
        <li data-role="list-divider" data-theme="c">B</li>
            <li><a href="#page2">A Common Love</a></li>
            <li><a href="#page3">Song 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#page4">Song 3</a></li>
        <li data-role="list-divider" data-theme="c">C</li>
            <li><a href="#page2">A Common Love</a></li>
            <li><a href="#page3">Song 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#page4">Song 3</a></li>
        <li data-role="list-divider" data-theme="c">D</li>
            <li><a href="#page2">A Common Love</a></li>
            <li><a href="#page3">Song 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#page4">Song 3</a></li>
        <li data-role="list-divider" data-theme="c">E</li>
            <li><a href="#page2">A Common Love</a></li>
            <li><a href="#page3">Song 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#page4">Song 3</a></li>
        <li data-role="list-divider" data-theme="c">F</li>
            <li><a href="#page2">A Common Love</a></li>
            <li><a href="#page3">Song 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#page4">Song 3</a></li>
        <li data-role="list-divider" data-theme="c">G</li>
            <li><a href="#page2">A Common Love</a></li>
            <li><a href="#page3">Song 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#page4">Song 3</a></li>
        <li data-role="list-divider" data-theme="c">H</li>
            <li><a href="#page2">A Common Love</a></li>
            <li><a href="#page3">Song 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#page4">Song 3</a></li>
        <li data-role="list-divider" data-theme="c">I</li>
            <li><a href="#page2">A Common Love</a></li>
            <li><a href="#page3">Song 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#page4">Song 3</a></li>
        <li data-role="list-divider" data-theme="c">J</li>
            <li><a href="#page2">A Common Love</a></li>
            <li><a href="#page3">Song 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#page4">Song 3</a></li>
        <li data-role="list-divider" data-theme="c">K</li>
            <li><a href="#page2">A Common Love</a></li>
            <li><a href="#page3">Song 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#page4">Song 3</a></li>
        <li data-role="list-divider" data-theme="c">L</li>
            <li><a href="#page2">A Common Love</a></li>
            <li><a href="#page3">Song 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#page4">Song 3</a></li>
        <li data-role="list-divider" data-theme="c">M</li>
            <li><a href="#page2">A Common Love</a></li>
            <li><a href="#page3">Song 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#page4">Song 3</a></li>
        <li data-role="list-divider" data-theme="c">N</li>
            <li><a href="#page2">A Common Love</a></li>
            <li><a href="#page3">Song 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#page4">Song 3</a></li>
        <li data-role="list-divider" data-theme="c">O</li>
            <li><a href="#page2">A Common Love</a></li>
            <li><a href="#page3">Song 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#page4">Song 3</a></li>
        <li data-role="list-divider" data-theme="c">P</li>
            <li><a href="#page2">A Common Love</a></li>
            <li><a href="#page3">Song 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#page4">Song 3</a></li>
        <li data-role="list-divider" data-theme="c">Q</li>
            <li><a href="#page2">A Common Love</a></li>
            <li><a href="#page3">Song 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#page4">Song 3</a></li>
        <li data-role="list-divider" data-theme="c">R</li>
            <li><a href="#page2">A Common Love</a></li>
            <li><a href="#page3">Song 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#page4">Song 3</a></li>
        <li data-role="list-divider" data-theme="c">S</li>
            <li><a href="#page2">A Common Love</a></li>
            <li><a href="#page3">Song 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#page4">Song 3</a></li>
        <li data-role="list-divider" data-theme="c">T</li>
            <li><a href="#page2">A Common Love</a></li>
            <li><a href="#page3">Song 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#page4">Song 3</a></li>
        <li data-role="list-divider" data-theme="c">U</li>
            <li><a href="#page2">A Common Love</a></li>
            <li><a href="#page3">Song 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#page4">Song 3</a></li>
        <li data-role="list-divider" data-theme="c">V</li>
            <li><a href="#page2">A Common Love</a></li>
            <li><a href="#page3">Song 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#page4">Song 3</a></li>
        <li data-role="list-divider" data-theme="c">W</li>
            <li><a href="#page2">A Common Love</a></li>
            <li><a href="#page3">Song 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#page4">Song 3</a></li>
        <li data-role="list-divider" data-theme="c">X</li>
            <li><a href="#page2">A Common Love</a></li>
            <li><a href="#page3">Song 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#page4">Song 3</a></li>
        <li data-role="list-divider" data-theme="c">Y</li>
            <li><a href="#page2">A Common Love</a></li>
            <li><a href="#page3">Song 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#page4">Song 3</a></li>
        <li data-role="list-divider" data-theme="c">Z</li>
            <li><a href="#page2">A Common Love</a></li>
            <li><a href="#page3">Song 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#page4">Song 3</a></li>
    </ul>       
</div>
```

I've been looking online for a couple of hours not, but I'm not finding a good solution I can get working. I used a list divider for each letter of the alphabet. Can I set a scroll bar to navigate to each list divider?

What would be the best way to add an alphabetical scroll bar to my list?

Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at the jQM Demo pages: http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/listview-autodividers-linkbar/

Answer (score 0):

Possible, but I wonder it'll be smooth navigation or not for such small screens

html

```
<div data-role="page" id="list">
    <div data-role="content">

        <ul data-role="listview">
            <li data-role="list-divider" id="a">A</li>
            <li class="showDetails">
                Adam Kinkaid
            </li>
            <li class="showDetails">Alex Wickerham</li>
            <li class="showDetails">Avery Johnson</li>
            <li data-role="list-divider" id="b">B</li>
            <li class="showDetails">Bob Cabot</li>
            <li data-role="list-divider" id="c">C</li>
            <li class="showDetails">Caleb Booth</li>
            <li class="showDetails">Christopher Adams</li>
            <li class="showDetails">Culver James</li>
            <li data-role="list-divider" id="d">D</li>
            <li class="showDetails">David Walsh</li>
            <li class="showDetails">Drake Alfred</li>
            <li data-role="list-divider" id="e">E</li>
            <li class="showDetails">Elizabeth Bacon</li>
            <li class="showDetails">Emery Parker</li>
            <li class="showDetails">Enid Voldon</li>
            <li data-role="list-divider" id="f">F</li>
            <li class="showDetails">Francis Wall</li>
            <li data-role="list-divider" id="g">G</li>
            <li class="showDetails">Graham Smith</li>
            <li class="showDetails">Greta Peete</li>
            <li data-role="list-divider" id="h">H</li>
            <li class="showDetails">Harvey Walls</li>
            <li data-role="list-divider" id="m">M</li>
            <li class="showDetails">Mike Farnsworth</li>
            <li class="showDetails">Murray Vanderbuilt</li>
            <li data-role="list-divider" id="n">N</li>
            <li class="showDetails">Nathan Williams</li>
            <li data-role="list-divider" id="p">P</li>
            <li class="showDetails">Paul Baker</li>
            <li class="showDetails">Pete Mason</li>
            <li data-role="list-divider" id="r">R</li>
            <li class="showDetails">Rod Tarker</li>
            <li data-role="list-divider" id="s">S</li>
            <li class="showDetails">Sawyer Wakefield</li>
        </ul>

        <ul data-role="none" id="list-navigation">
            <li>
                <p id="list-1" class="scrollToSelected"><strong>1</strong></p>
                <p id="list-2" class="scrollToSelected"><strong>2</strong></p>
                <p id="list-3" class="scrollToSelected"><strong>3</strong></p>
                <p id="list-a" class="scrollToSelected"><strong>A</strong></p>
                <p id="list-b" class="scrollToSelected"><strong>B</strong></p>
                <p id="list-c" class="scrollToSelected"><strong>C</strong></p>
                <p id="list-d" class="scrollToSelected"><strong>D</strong></p>
                <p id="list-e" class="scrollToSelected"><strong>E</strong></p>
                <p id="list-f" class="scrollToSelected"><strong>F</strong></p>
                <p id="list-g" class="scrollToSelected"><strong>G</strong></p>
                <p id="list-h" class="scrollToSelected"><strong>H</strong></p>
                <p id="list-i" class="scrollToSelected"><strong>I</strong></p>
                <p id="list-j" class="scrollToSelected"><strong>J</strong></p>
                <p id="list-k" class="scrollToSelected"><strong>K</strong></p>
                <p id="list-l" class="scrollToSelected"><strong>L</strong></p>
                <p id="list-m" class="scrollToSelected"><strong>M</strong></p>
                <p id="list-n" class="scrollToSelected"><strong>N</strong></p>
                <p id="list-o" class="scrollToSelected"><strong>O</strong></p>
                <p id="list-p" class="scrollToSelected"><strong>P</strong></p>
                <p id="list-q" class="scrollToSelected"><strong>Q</strong></p>
                <p id="list-r" class="scrollToSelected"><strong>R</strong></p>
                <p id="list-s" class="scrollToSelected"><strong>S</strong></p>
                <p id="list-t" class="scrollToSelected"><strong>T</strong></p>
                <p id="list-u" class="scrollToSelected"><strong>U</strong></p>
                <p id="list-v" class="scrollToSelected"><strong>V</strong></p>
                <p id="list-w" class="scrollToSelected"><strong>W</strong></p>
                <p id="list-x" class="scrollToSelected"><strong>X</strong></p>
                <p id="list-y" class="scrollToSelected"><strong>Y</strong></p>
                <p id="list-z" class="scrollToSelected"><strong>Z</strong></p>
            </li>
        </ul>

    </div>
</div>

<div data-role="page" id="details">
    <div data-role="content">

        <ul data-role="listview">
            <li data-role="list-divider">Details</li>
            <li><a href="#list" data-direction="reverse">List</a></li>
        </ul>
        <br />
        <p>
            Here are the details you were looking for
        </p>

    </div>
</div>
```

css

```
#list-navigation {
    color:#696969;

    position:absolute;
    right:0px;
    top:0px;
    z-index:200;
}
```

JS

```
$('.scrollToSelected').bind('click', function() {
    var view = $(this).attr('id');
    var list = view.split('-');
    var elem = $("#"+list[1]);

    // not sure if this is offset or position
    var position = elem.position(); 
    var offset   = elem.offset();


    $.mobile.silentScroll(position.top);


});

$('.showDetails').bind('click', function() {
    $.mobile.changePage( "#details", { transition: "slideup"} );
});
```

Fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/qXT9Z/32/